# MPEP and Case Laws

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, patent-applications, patent-services, utility-patent

How patent Examiners either memorize or manage themselves while citing all the relevant case laws and sections of MPEP during issuance of an Office Action?

Comment: They copy paste the same stuff over and over and look up the unusual things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides copying and pasting, they work in modest sized art units and often further specialize within an art unit. If you see laser printer power supplies all day every day you probably get pretty good at that area of technology. Also, they do not cite case law widely. If it isn't in the MPEP or some written USPTO guidelines, they do not cite it.